# Enabling simultaneous turns in Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete + HD+ patch over TCP/IP

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

How can I enable simultaneous turns in Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete + [HD+ patch](https://sites.google.com/site/heroes3hd/rus/description/hd_plus) over TCP/IP?

From what I found on the site I should be having the following options in multiplayer:

[image]

But instead I only have these options when hosting multiplayer over TCP/IP:

[image]

I just tried to join a game in the online lobby and got the following message:

[image]

I wonder if this restriction applies to TCP/IP also. Eg. I would need to pay to play simultaneous turns over TCP/IP.

**Update:**

For the sake of testing I paid for Daddy Status to see if that allows playing simultaneous turns over TCP/IP and that did not work, it is still unavailable.

But now I can play simultaneous turns in the game lobby:

[image]

Based on what it says [here](http://ih938139.vds.myihor.ru/simturn) I'm thinking that maybe if all players who joined the TCP/IP host have daddy status then enabling simultaneous turns would work.